# The sidebar is not hiding in smaller devices

Tags: layout, responsive-design, tailwind-css, styling

My problem is I have created a sidebar but when I hide it using transform and translate, It hides in laptop but not in smaller devices.
I have used tailwind css

[Mobile Device Problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLF9i.png)

My code is:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { AiOutlineShoppingCart, AiFillCloseCircle,AiOutlinePlusCircle,AiOutlineMinusCircle } from "react-icons/ai";
import { useRef } from "react";

const Navbar = () => {

  const toggleCart = () => {
    if (ref.current.classList.contains('translate-x-full')) {
      ref.current.classList.remove('translate-x-full')
      ref.current.classList.add('translate-x-0')
  }
    else if (!ref.current.classList.contains('translate-x-full')) {
      ref.current.classList.remove('translate-x-0')
      ref.current.classList.add('translate-x-full')
  }
  }
  
  const ref = useRef()

  return (
    <div>
      <header className="text-gray-600 body-font shadow-xl">
        <div className="container mx-auto flex flex-wrap p-5 flex-col md:flex-row items-center">
          <Link
            href={"/"}
            className="flex title-font font-medium items-center text-gray-900 mb-4 md:mb-0"
          >
            <a>
              <Image src={"/mithanSweets.png"} height={45} width={256} />
            </a>
          </Link>
          <nav className="md:ml-auto md:mr-auto flex flex-wrap items-center text-base justify-center">
            <Link href={"/categories/burger"}>
              <a className="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900">Burgers</a>
            </Link>
            <Link href={"/categories/italian"}>
              <a className="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900">Italian</a>
            </Link>
            <Link href={"/categories/noodles"}>
              <a className="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900">Noodles</a>
            </Link>
            <Link href={"/categories/pizza"}>
              <a className="mr-5 hover:text-gray-900">Pizzas</a>
            </Link>
          </nav>
          <div
            onClick={toggleCart}
            className=" cursor-pointer inline-flex items-center bg-gray-100 border-0 py-1 px-3 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-200 rounded text-base mt-4 md:mt-0"
          >
            <AiOutlineShoppingCart className="mr-3 text-2xl" />
            Cart
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          ref={ref}
          className=" w-72 sideCart absolute top-0 right-0 bg-gray-200 px-8 py-10 transform transition-transform translate-x-full"
        >
          <h2 className="font-bold text-xl text-center">Shopping Cart</h2>
          <span
            onClick={toggleCart}
            className="absolute top-5 right-2 cursor-pointer text-2xl text-gray-600"
          >
            <AiFillCloseCircle />
          </span>
          <ol className="list-decimal font-semibold">
            <li>
              <div className="item flex my-5">
              <div className="w-2/3 font-semibold">Spicy Seafood Pasta</div>
              <div className="w-1/3 font-semibold flex items-center justify-center text-lg"><AiOutlineMinusCircle className="cursor-pointer" /><span className="mx-2">1</span><AiOutlinePlusCircle className="cursor-pointer" /></div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

And It is working fine in laptop device

[Laptop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND8FJ.png)

but not in inspect mode

[Inspect mode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQASv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you can do is to refresh the page. Secondly below is another approach, although its not the perfect solution but it works for me.

**Solution**

One thing you can do is that instead of translating you can `hide` and `unhide` the side bar like this

```
const toggleCart = () => {
    if (ref.current.classList.contains("hidden")) {
      ref.current.classList.remove("hidden");
      ref.current.classList.add('block');
  }
    else if (!ref.current.classList.contains("hidden")) {
      ref.current.classList.remove('block');
      ref.current.classList.add('hidden');
  }
  }
```

And then change the sidecart as

```
<div
          ref={ref}
          className=" w-72 sideCart absolute top-0 right-0 bg-gray-200 px-8 py-10 transform transition-transform hidden"
        >
          <h2 className="font-bold text-xl text-center">Shopping Cart</h2>
          <span
            onClick={toggleCart}
            className="absolute top-5 right-2 cursor-pointer text-2xl text-gray-600"
          >
            <AiFillCloseCircle />
          </span>
          <ol className="list-decimal font-semibold">
            <li>
              <div className="item flex my-5">
              <div className="w-2/3 font-semibold">Spicy Seafood Pasta</div>
              <div className="w-1/3 font-semibold flex items-center justify-center text-lg"><AiOutlineMinusCircle className="cursor-pointer" /><span className="mx-2">1</span><AiOutlinePlusCircle className="cursor-pointer" /></div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </div>
```